# Parse JSON from REST API

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse JSON from a RestAPI with this code:

```
if var dict : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
    println("Dictionary: \(dict)")
} else {
    println("nil")
    var resultString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(resultString)
}
```

But the dictionary is not created(I think that is not a valid JSON format), and I only receive the string like this:

> Optional(set_metadata('allergy',[{"id":"396","shortDescription":"Dairy-Free","longDescription":"Dairy-Free","searchValue":"396^Dairy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"397","shortDescription":"Egg-Free","longDescription":"Egg-Free","searchValue":"397^Egg-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"393","shortDescription":"Gluten-Free","longDescription":"Gluten-Free","searchValue":"393^Gluten-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"394","shortDescription":"Peanut-Free","longDescription":"Peanut-Free","searchValue":"394^Peanut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"398","shortDescription":"Seafood-Free","longDescription":"Seafood-Free","searchValue":"398^Seafood-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"399","shortDescription":"Sesame-Free","longDescription":"Sesame-Free","searchValue":"399^Sesame-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"400","shortDescription":"Soy-Free","longDescription":"Soy-Free","searchValue":"400^Soy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"401","shortDescription":"Sulfite-Free","longDescription":"Sulfite-Free","searchValue":"401^Sulfite-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"395","shortDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","longDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","searchValue":"395^Tree Nut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"392","shortDescription":"Wheat-Free","longDescription":"Wheat-Free","searchValue":"392^Wheat-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]}]);)

How can I convert this to a NSDictionary? Or some structure that I can handle with this?

Comment: There could be invalid characters at the beginning of the JSON. Try cutting them off, and than do the JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid characters at the beginning and at the end of your response.

I would suggest the following to overcome this issue:

Convert the response into NSString.
Than cut off the " set_metadata('allergy' " from the beginning and the last 3 characters.

Then you should end up with the following string:

```
[{"id":"396","shortDescription":"Dairy-Free","longDescription":"Dairy-Free","searchValue":"396^Dairy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"397","shortDescription":"Egg-Free","longDescription":"Egg-Free","searchValue":"397^Egg-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"393","shortDescription":"Gluten-Free","longDescription":"Gluten-Free","searchValue":"393^Gluten-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"394","shortDescription":"Peanut-Free","longDescription":"Peanut-Free","searchValue":"394^Peanut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"398","shortDescription":"Seafood-Free","longDescription":"Seafood-Free","searchValue":"398^Seafood-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"399","shortDescription":"Sesame-Free","longDescription":"Sesame-Free","searchValue":"399^Sesame-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"400","shortDescription":"Soy-Free","longDescription":"Soy-Free","searchValue":"400^Soy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"401","shortDescription":"Sulfite-Free","longDescription":"Sulfite-Free","searchValue":"401^Sulfite-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"395","shortDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","longDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","searchValue":"395^Tree Nut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"392","shortDescription":"Wheat-Free","longDescription":"Wheat-Free","searchValue":"392^Wheat-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]}]
```

now lets convert the string back to nsdata:

```
let serializeableData = dataString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

and to JSON:

```
var jsonErrorOptional : NSError?
 let json: AnyObject!
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(serializeableData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 2))
            } catch let error as NSError {
                jsonErrorOptional = error
                json = nil
            } catch {
                fatalError()
            }
```

Check if the JSON is valid

```
if let _json = json as? [[String : AnyObject]]  {
     // _json should be a valid swift dictionary
 }
```

I know it seems a bit fuzzy solution, but it worked for me before

Comment: Ok, i did this, but how can i convert back to JSON? And is not better to covert directly to NSDictionary?

Comment: please see my edits. Why convert it to NSDictionary, when you are doing swift?

Comment: I want to store the NSDictionary into a list of objects with this JSON, so, I didn't use your solution, but this works fine for me:  let data1 = resultString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            
            var json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data1!, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil)

Comment: NSJSONSerialization throws ErrorType and not NSError.  So you'll alway get fatalError()

Answer (score 1):

The string you posted is a log statement from the console. This is the statement:

```
Optional(set_metadata('allergy',[{"id":"396","shortDescription":"Dairy-Free","longDescription":"Dairy-Free","searchValue":"396^Dairy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"397","shortDescription":"Egg-Free","longDescription":"Egg-Free","searchValue":"397^Egg-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"393","shortDescription":"Gluten-Free","longDescription":"Gluten-Free","searchValue":"393^Gluten-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"394","shortDescription":"Peanut-Free","longDescription":"Peanut-Free","searchValue":"394^Peanut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"398","shortDescription":"Seafood-Free","longDescription":"Seafood-Free","searchValue":"398^Seafood-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"399","shortDescription":"Sesame-Free","longDescription":"Sesame-Free","searchValue":"399^Sesame-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"400","shortDescription":"Soy-Free","longDescription":"Soy-Free","searchValue":"400^Soy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"401","shortDescription":"Sulfite-Free","longDescription":"Sulfite-Free","searchValue":"401^Sulfite-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"395","shortDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","longDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","searchValue":"395^Tree Nut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"392","shortDescription":"Wheat-Free","longDescription":"Wheat-Free","searchValue":"392^Wheat-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]}]);)
```

Your string is optional, so the actual string is this:

```
set_metadata('allergy',[{"id":"396","shortDescription":"Dairy-Free","longDescription":"Dairy-Free","searchValue":"396^Dairy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"397","shortDescription":"Egg-Free","longDescription":"Egg-Free","searchValue":"397^Egg-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"393","shortDescription":"Gluten-Free","longDescription":"Gluten-Free","searchValue":"393^Gluten-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"394","shortDescription":"Peanut-Free","longDescription":"Peanut-Free","searchValue":"394^Peanut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"398","shortDescription":"Seafood-Free","longDescription":"Seafood-Free","searchValue":"398^Seafood-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"399","shortDescription":"Sesame-Free","longDescription":"Sesame-Free","searchValue":"399^Sesame-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"400","shortDescription":"Soy-Free","longDescription":"Soy-Free","searchValue":"400^Soy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"401","shortDescription":"Sulfite-Free","longDescription":"Sulfite-Free","searchValue":"401^Sulfite-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"395","shortDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","longDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","searchValue":"395^Tree Nut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"392","shortDescription":"Wheat-Free","longDescription":"Wheat-Free","searchValue":"392^Wheat-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]}]);
```

This is not valid JSON. The JSON actually starts at the first `[`. The following is the JSON you need to parse:

```
[{"id":"396","shortDescription":"Dairy-Free","longDescription":"Dairy-Free","searchValue":"396^Dairy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"397","shortDescription":"Egg-Free","longDescription":"Egg-Free","searchValue":"397^Egg-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"393","shortDescription":"Gluten-Free","longDescription":"Gluten-Free","searchValue":"393^Gluten-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"394","shortDescription":"Peanut-Free","longDescription":"Peanut-Free","searchValue":"394^Peanut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"398","shortDescription":"Seafood-Free","longDescription":"Seafood-Free","searchValue":"398^Seafood-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"399","shortDescription":"Sesame-Free","longDescription":"Sesame-Free","searchValue":"399^Sesame-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"400","shortDescription":"Soy-Free","longDescription":"Soy-Free","searchValue":"400^Soy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"401","shortDescription":"Sulfite-Free","longDescription":"Sulfite-Free","searchValue":"401^Sulfite-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"395","shortDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","longDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","searchValue":"395^Tree Nut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]},{"id":"392","shortDescription":"Wheat-Free","longDescription":"Wheat-Free","searchValue":"392^Wheat-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US"]}]
```

The same string pretty printed:

```
[
  {
    "id": "396",
    "shortDescription": "Dairy-Free",
    "longDescription": "Dairy-Free",
    "searchValue": "396^Dairy-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "397",
    "shortDescription": "Egg-Free",
    "longDescription": "Egg-Free",
    "searchValue": "397^Egg-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "393",
    "shortDescription": "Gluten-Free",
    "longDescription": "Gluten-Free",
    "searchValue": "393^Gluten-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "394",
    "shortDescription": "Peanut-Free",
    "longDescription": "Peanut-Free",
    "searchValue": "394^Peanut-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "398",
    "shortDescription": "Seafood-Free",
    "longDescription": "Seafood-Free",
    "searchValue": "398^Seafood-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "399",
    "shortDescription": "Sesame-Free",
    "longDescription": "Sesame-Free",
    "searchValue": "399^Sesame-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "400",
    "shortDescription": "Soy-Free",
    "longDescription": "Soy-Free",
    "searchValue": "400^Soy-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "401",
    "shortDescription": "Sulfite-Free",
    "longDescription": "Sulfite-Free",
    "searchValue": "401^Sulfite-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "395",
    "shortDescription": "Tree Nut-Free",
    "longDescription": "Tree Nut-Free",
    "searchValue": "395^Tree Nut-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "392",
    "shortDescription": "Wheat-Free",
    "longDescription": "Wheat-Free",
    "searchValue": "392^Wheat-Free",
    "type": "allergy",
    "localesAvailableIn": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  }
]
```